# Team Build error : ASPNETCOMPILER : error ASPRUNTIME: '/localhost:8080' is not a valid virtual path. Any suggestion?

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2008-sp1, tfsbuild, aspnet-compiler

I am trying to build Web Application solution built using VS 2008 and facing the following error.

**ASPNETCOMPILER : error ASPRUNTIME: '/localhost:8080' is not a valid virtual path.**

I have absolutely no clue how and why is is occurring? Is it related with the deploy project settings or web site properties? The Solution is checked into the source control.

The same works for a different branch of the same solution and the build occurs without any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the project properties for the web site, under the MSBuild options,
change the Output Folder path, removing the port number.

Answer (score 0):

In your web project solution right click the project (which is like http://localhost:xxx/_1/)  in the solution and click Property Pages. A new Dialog will open saying " http://youwebsiteName:xxxx/_1/ Property Pages" as Title. In this dialog click "MSBuild Options".

On clicking this option the contents of the dialog will change and certain properties having checkboxes and single text field will be displayed. The first text field will be saying "Output folder" and inside the text field there will be a path written that says something like "d:\data\allProjects\WebProject\localhost:8080".

Obviously it is not valid path as you cannot create a folder having ":" in the fodler/path name. So remove this colon and port number and save it. This will solve the problem regarding the valid virtual path.